# Insert accumulated total to my table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to calculate running total like this (`idd` is not primary or foreign key)

```
idd    svalue      acctotal
1       5             5
2       6             11
1       2             13
3       4             17
2       1             18
```

and so on

I work in many trigger but it didn't work:

```
 create trigger acc on detail 
 for update, insert 
 as 
     DECLARE @AccountID INT
     DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR

     SET @getAccountID = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT idd
        FROM detail

     declare @tot as int
     set @tot = (select sum(dvalues) from detail)

     OPEN @getAccountID

     FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @AccountID

     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
        PRINT @AccountID

        UPDATE detail 
        SET acctotal = @tot

        FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @AccountID
     END

     CLOSE @getAccountID
```

Comment: Do you really need to store the accumulated value?  Why not just calculate it on output?  If you do store it, you need a `delete` trigger as well.

Comment: yes realy i want this... the output is easy mr @gorden linoff

Comment: Without some kind of order by this makes no sense. You need a column to tell you what order those records need to be added in. Take Mr Linoff's advice - this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: its impossible ... there is no bad idea on programming @electricliama

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but without a column defining an order in your table you will get 'unpredictable results'

Comment: ok i will wait for some one to solve my problem ,,, every new insert it must calculate the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do it something like:

```
@tot = (select top 1 isnull(acctotal, 0) + @newvalue from detail order by acctotal desc)
```

This will only work if you're only ever dealing with positive number though... The advice about something unique to order by is the best way. Even just adding a seed column would work to order by.

Regards

Liam

Answer (score 0):

You can write the trigger as:

```
create trigger acc on detail for update, insert 
as 

;with cte as
(
    select idd,svalue,acctotal, row_number() over ( order by (select 1)) as rownum
    from detail
)
Update T1 set acctotal = 
        (SELECT SUM(svalue)
         from cte as T2
         where T1.rownum >= T2.rownum )        
from cte T1

Go
```

[Check Demo here..](http://rextester.com/VYUUF86454)

Comment: My two statements stand: bad idea, you need an order by, but I'm guessing you'll be happy with this.

Comment: I can assure you that it doesn't work perfectly. But I'll let you find that out for yourself.

Comment: hhhh >>> why u no believe ,,, take the code and try it... salam... @electricliama